# Long cache refresh with guaranteed response

Tags: c#, cache

I am trying to ensure that (once a cache item is populated) even if it's refresh object takes a long time to retrieve, the original cache item can be requested.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Caching;

namespace LongCacheTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cacher.Add("key", "object", Get);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static Object Get()
        {
            // load big file from disck
            return "stuff";
        }
    }

    public class Cacheable
    {
        public delegate Object CacheEntryGet();

        public Object Obj { get; set; }
        public CacheEntryGet Getter { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cacher
    {
        private static MemoryCache _cache = null;

        private static MemoryCache Cache => _cache = _cache ?? new MemoryCache("long");

        private static CacheItemPolicy Policy => new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)),
            Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default,
            RemovedCallback = DidRemove
        };

        public static void DidRemove(CacheEntryRemovedArguments args)
        {
            Cache.Add(args.CacheItem.Key, args.CacheItem.Value, Policy);

            var item = args.CacheItem.Value as Cacheable;

            item.Obj = item.Getter();

            Cache.Remove(args.CacheItem.Key);
            Cache.Add(args.CacheItem.Key, item, Policy);
        }

        public static void Add(string key, Object obj, Cacheable.CacheEntryGet getter)
        {
            var item = new Cacheable{
                Obj = obj,
                Getter = getter
            };

            Cache.Add(key, item, Policy);
        }
    }
}
```

The practice here is to provide a method `Getter` and cache it alongside the cached `Object`. When the cache item expires, it is reinserted and the `Getter` method is called to get the refresh object. Once the fresh object is retrieved it replaces the original cache item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I use this?

I don't understand how to use this.  It took me some time to understand the reason for the getter, and I can't see how to retrieve anything from this cache.

#### Why do I need to `Add` the value when I have the delegate?

In the `Add` method, it doesn't make sense to add provide both a value and a method that calculates the value; it is very likely that someone will pass in inconsistent arguments and get unexpected results.  It should suffice to simply pass in the delegate, and let the value calculate itself.

#### Why is this static?

It is very dangerous to have one global cache holding every different type.  You should allow for multiple caches for different purposes, and then you can...

#### Make this cache generic

Nobody likes to cast from `Object`.  Your interface should be `Cacheable<T>`, so that we can check at compile time that the type to be returned is what we expect.

#### Your response is not guaranteed

Your callback is only called after the item has been removed from the cache.  Even if you add the previous value back straight away, a poorly-timed interrupt could have another thread searching for a key in that split-millisecond it's not there.

Comment: Thanks for your help! If I wanted to post the revised code, should it be as an updated to the original post or a new post?

Comment: @MattW Refer to [this meta post for the acceptable options](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765/120114)